# Problemas com o ValidationSummary - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou com problemas com ValidationSummary na minha aplicação que gerencia **Cursos**, tenho uma tela onde o aluno faz sua inscrição em um curso e caso ele tente se inscrever no mesmo **curso** novamente deveria aparecer a mensagem **Aluno já está inscrito no curso**. Só que não está aparecendo essa mensagem na `View` para o aluno.

**Action**

```
    // GET
    public ActionResult Inscricao()
    {
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno == null)
            return View("MeusCursos");

        return View(db.Cursos.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Inscricao(int inscricaoId)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //Aqui pega o usuario logado
            Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
            if (aluno == null)
                return View("MeusCursos");

            var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == inscricaoId);
            if (curso == null)
                return View("MeusCursos");

            if (curso.Qtd_Vagas <= 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Qtd_Vagas", "Não existem mais vagas para este curso.");
                return RedirectToAction("Inscricao");
            }

            var alunoCurso = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Curso.Id == inscricaoId && ac.Aluno.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
            if (alunoCurso != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("alunoCurso", "Aluno já está inscrito no curso.");
                return RedirectToAction("Inscricao", "Curso");
            }

            alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso
            {
                Aluno = aluno,
                Curso = curso
            };

            db.AlunoCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
            db.SaveChanges();

            curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
            db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            scope.Complete();
        }

        return View(db.Cursos.ToList());
    }
```

**View**

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Curso>

<h2>Catálago de Cursos</h2>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Sigla
        </th>
        <th>
            Ementa
        </th>
        <th>
            Inicio
        </th>
        <th>
            Fim
        </th>
        <th>
            Turno
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantidade de Vagas
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sigla)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Ementa", "Curso")" data_toggle="modal" data_target="#modalaviso">Ementa</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Inicio)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Fim)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Turno)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)" readonly class="Status" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qtd_Vagas)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @if (item.Qtd_Vagas > 0)
                        {
                        <input type="submit" value="Inscrição" name="detalhes" class="inscricao btn btn-success" data_toggle="modal" data_target="#modalAviso" data-inscricaoid="@item.Id"/>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input type="submit" value="Não há vagas" name="detalhes" class="inscricao btn btn-default" disabled="disabled" />
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
<div class="form-group">

    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><input type="button" value="Voltar" class="btn btn-danger" /></a>

</div>
<br />


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Inscricao/",
                    data: {inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid")},
                    success: function() {
                            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

}

Comment: Ao inspecionar o HTML, a mensagem é escrita dentro dele?

Comment: Não @Cigano, não aparece nada.

Comment: @Novato é por que você usa RedirectToAction, e não retorna um model para essa View, como é que você vai add um modelState se você não retorna um model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repare que:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Não sei se você chegou a pressionar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Espaço</kbd> pra verificar o que é aquele `true` ali:

[image: Code Completion]

`excludePropertyErrors` exclui todo e qualquer erro relacionado com propriedades, incluindo aqueles que estão definidos com a propriedade vazia (seu caso). Mude para:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

Esta solução funciona se você quiser imprimir as mensagens de erro no topo da página. No seu caso, você está definindo por propriedade:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Qtd_Vagas", "Não existem mais vagas para este curso.");
```

Neste caso, o correto é usar:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Qtd_Vagas)
```

Comment: Nada @Cigano, ainda assim não apresentou a mensagem na tela.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode trabalhar com [`TempData[""]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx) para levar essa informação. Neste caso, você faria isto em seu `controller`:

```
     if (curso.Qtd_Vagas <= 0)
                {
                    TempData["MensagemErro"] = "Não existem mais vagas para este curso.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Inscricao");
                }
```

E em sua `View` você chama a mensagem, caso ocorra o erro. Segue um exemplo:

**Edição**

```
//A mensagem de error será apresentada aqui
@TempData["MensagemErro"]
```

Comment: Não funcionou @Randrade. O if do tempData eu posso colocar em qualquer lugar da View?

Comment: @Novato o `if` é simplesmente para não apresentar a classe, caso não haja mensagem. Neste exemplo eu estou utilizando uma classe do [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples). O importante mesmo, é você deixar em sua `View` o código: `@TempData["MensagemErro"]`. Editei a resposta, teste dessa forma

Comment: Nada @Randrade, não sei porque não tá aparecendo.

Comment: Ao debugar, ele está entrando no `if` e preenchendo o `TempData`?
Lembrando que você está retornando para a `Action` Inscrição, logo o `TempData` deverá estar na `View` correspondente.
E apenas para esclarecer. Você está querendo apenas retornar a mensagem para a `View`, correto?

Comment: O que eu preciso é o seguinte, quando o "aluno" clicar no botão inscrição e ele já estiver inscrito deve aparecer a mensagem que ele já está cadastrado no curso. Entendeu?!